# After updating React-Select: Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-select/dist/react-select.css

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have tried updating my old dependencies in current react project, but encountered this issue

Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-select/dist/react-select.css

I have manually checked `react-select` folder in `node_modules` couldn't find any `react-select.css` file.

couldn't find any reference regarding this thing,

Package version `3.0.8`
Solution: removing css imports clear my error

They removed the CSS-class-based styling and therefore you don't need to import the CSS file anymore.

More info can be found in the upgrade Guide: https://react-select.com/upgrade-guide#new-styles-api

Thank You @Mastacheata for the details

Comment: What version of react-select are you using?

Comment: @wentjun react-select version is `3.0.8`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you upgraded from v1 to v2, you should definitely read their upgrade guide. The new major version is a major release for a good reason.

They removed the CSS-class-based styling and therefore you don't need to import the CSS file anymore. Instead they now define the CSS styles for their components right inside the code.

More info can be found in the upgrade Guide:
https://react-select.com/upgrade-guide#new-styles-api

Comment: i have done that and removed css imports,

 application was breaking, styling got upside down,

Comment: i think that was due to multiple packages updating which contain break changes,

Comment: @HanzlaHabib You shouldn't upgrade major versions without checking whats changed. If you don't want to adapt your code to v2, change your version back to v1.

Comment: yes i downgraded most of packages, its was request from product owner to update, i told them that will break things because packages are tied to semantic versioning, and if updated packages which contain change in API that will cost us time to make it compatible with latest changes, he still insisted to test it once and that clearly fails
btw thanks for your time

Comment: Always update 1 package after another unless you're definitely sure you know there are no changes that could affect you.

Just do the other updates incrementally, that way you see which package was responsible for breaking things. (learned that lesson the hard way)